# Why does short band (high frequency) radio travel longer than low frequency?

Tags: rf, frequency, radio, propagation, wavelength

In physics, we are taught that longer wavelength (lower frequency) have a lower attenuation in air, and thus is able to travel longer distances.

However, when talking about radio channels, short wave (high frequency) is considered better over long distance? How can this be?

Comment: Hmmm. The situation is more complex than just figuring the attenuation in air. Certain bands are able to bounce back and forth between the layers of the atmosphere and the surface of earth, so traveling far beyond the horizon. For example VHF does not get attenuated much by air, but it still can't go over the horizon to any appreciable extent because it doesn't reflect off the atmospheric layers.

Comment: http://www.mike-willis.com/Tutorial/PF5.htm

Comment: The "short waves" in question can be reflected by conductive gas (plasma) layers in the ionosphere acting as reflectors, overcoming line-of-sight limitations. But you're talking about MHz to tens of MHz, not GHz. Those waves were "short" in the 1930s...

Comment: Allow me to be pedantic and point out that the *Free Space Path Loss*, or FSPL is not the same as attenuation. The signal is not being dissipated by anything, it is simply the spreading out of the power over a larger area as it moves away from the source that results in a lower power/area, and as a result the receiving antenna will not be able to capture as much power, ie, receive a weaker signal. I think you need to go up to around 60 GHz where you have an oxygen absorption line to see a meaningful increase in atmospheric attenuation.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't. I think you're confused by a bit of terminology. "Shortwave" and "high frequency" are terms invented over a hundred years ago to refer to some of the *longest* wavelengths and *lowest* frequencies in common use today. At the time, anything over a few MHz was an impressive feat of electrical engineering. Today, we can work in the GHz and tens of GHz, and more experimentally, the hundreds of GHz and low THz.